# Is there any tool to automatically create template for model in django

Tags: django, templates, model

I am new in django and I have some experience in Jsf within Netbeans.
In netbeans, when we have entity classes, it can automatically create jsf page for this entity classes to list, create and view.
Is there any tool to automatically create template for model in django?

Answer (score 1):

There is Django admin which you can connect your models to:

[Django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/)

It's as simple as a line of code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Author

admin.site.register(Author)
```

And you can do all sorts of customizations.